# Web Development In Java Using Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I am trying to implement a web application(university project) in java using the following Frameworks

Spring Dependency Injection 
Spring AOP (Logging and Transaction Management)
Spring DAO
JDBC or HIBERNATE 
Spring MVC
Log4J

I create a new Web Application in Netbeans and it gives me a bunch of Files and folders by default.

Could anyone explain me what are the files ?

Where shall i put the code for the data access layer and business Logic?

Or where can i found a basic tutorial to get started(with data access layer, business layer and possibly code example)?

Thanks

Comment: You should probably consult with someone on how to structure your project and architect your application. It sounds like you threw out some buzzwords and don't understand why or how you would implement any of those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One area in which NetBeans is **very** good is the online documentation and tutorials so leverage them:

- [Introduction to the Spring Framework](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/quickstart-webapps-spring.html)
- [Developing a Spring Framework MVC application step-by-step using NetBeans and GlassFish](http://wiki.netbeans.org/SpringMVConNetBeansGlassFish)
- [Using Hibernate in a Web Application](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/hibernate-webapp.html)
- etc etc

Answer (score 1):

That is a ton of Java frameworks for a Web Dev course at a university.  My advice would be to start small, because you don't need all of those libraries to get a working web application.

As you found, Netbeans is doing a lot of work for you that you really need to know to be effective.  Do a simple JSP or Java Servlet tutorial to get something up and running quickly from scratch on a lightweight app server like Jetty or Tomcat.

Also, please take a look at what [Model View Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) architecture is prior to diving into Hibernate or SpringMVC.  This is a critical step!

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to list the files that you got, but I think I can guess:

1. WEB-INF/classes is where your compiled .java code will go.  Everything should be in packages, so the directory and package structures should match.  Your Spring XML and Hibernate .hbm.xml configuration  files will go here as well, because that directory is automatically in the CLASSPATH of your web context.
2. WEB-INF/lib is where your 3rd party .jar files go.  All the Spring and Hibernate JARs, plus all their dependencies, belong here.
3. The WEB-INF/web.xml is where you'll map in the Spring front controller/dispatcher servlet, the context loader listener, etc.

I don't know what others you got.  If you list others, I'll try to explain.

Answer (score 0):

Here is Netbeans web application + hibernate tutorial.

http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/hibernate-webapp.html

code for business and data access would go under

- your project name/Source Packages/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your input, Drew.

I'm working on a Capstone project and we are thinking about using Netbeans for our Web-based project but were unsure about how difficult it would be to make the Web Based application in a relatively short amount of time.  The application is for a College Testing Center and the application will track testing information and data for testing personnel and instructors at our college.  I was going to try and follow a few tutorials here on the Netbeans site.

Thanks for your time.

[PHP and HTML5 Learning Trail with Netbeans.](https://netbeans.org/kb/trails/php.html).

[Here's a video as well.](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/html5-gettingstarted-screencast.html)

[Youtube Simple Web App instruction video.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=On3kcaQ8xYs)